# Параметры сессии пользователя в Django

Tags: django, сессия

В проекте для некоторых нужд используются глобальные переменные и доступ к ним в отдельных `view` определяется с помощью оператора `global <'имя переменной'>`.

По факту при многопользовательском доступе данные глобальные переменные сохраняют одно и тоже значение для каждого авторизованного в системе пользователя, что совершенно не то, что планировалось достичь.

> Например, в глобальную переменную сохраняются параметры поискового
>   запроса, чтобы установить их же при возврате на страницу поиска.

Предполагалось, что эти глобальные переменные имеют для каждой сессии авторизовавшихся пользователей своё значение, что оказалось ошибочным предположением.

**В связи с этим два вопроса:**

Каким образом можно использовать параметры сессии чтобы обособить глобальные ресурсы системы для каждого пользователя? Или как, вообще, традиционно это делается?

Comment: Можно в куки сохранять, вас такая опция устроит?

Comment: Как вариант, сохранение в куки подходит. А если эти параметры должны быть надежно защищены?

Comment: `https` вам в помощь :)

Comment: Какие ещё могут быть использованы способы сохранения глобальных параметров для каждого пользователя, кроме сохранения в БД? Можно ли использовать ресурсы сесcии для этих целей?

Comment: Есть еще такая вещь 
https://pypi.org/project/django-globals/

Comment: Данное приложение делает возможным доступ к объектам request и user вне текущего представления. Тем самым сохраняется возможность использования предыдущих данных request при отображении новой формы запроса с предыдущими параметрами. Предполагаю, что этот механизм подойдет для моей задачи. В любом случае благодарю за предложенные решения!